# search only the current directory on key press in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am currently using 13.04. Till 12.10 in file browser (nautilus) pressing any key press will select the directory starting with that key. For example when i do the below

- Opening a nautilus
- Press D (all folder that starts with D will be selected and not the subfolders)

Whereas in ubuntu 13.04 it searches all the folders in the current directories and in sub directories too.

Is it possible to restrict the search only to current directories by any configuration. Thanks for your guidance.